# Arraylist updated by set() method does not update the referenced arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two array lists myArrayList01 and myArrayList02. I am appending myArrayList02 to myArrayList01 using addAll(). As per my knowlendge, addAll() only creates a shallow copy of the arraylist, ie., only the references of myArrayList02 are copied into myArrayList01.

This implies any change in the elements of myArrayList02 will be reflected in myArrayList01 too. But when I change the one of the elements of the list using the set method, the change is not updated in myArrayList01. What is the reason for this?

```
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> myArrayList01=new ArrayList<>();
    myArrayList01.add(new StringBuilder("uno"));
    myArrayList01.add(new StringBuilder("dos"));
    myArrayList01.add(new StringBuilder("tres"));

    ArrayList<StringBuilder> myArrayList02=new ArrayList<>();
    myArrayList02.add(new StringBuilder("one"));
    myArrayList02.add(new StringBuilder("two"));
    myArrayList02.add(new StringBuilder("three"));

    myArrayList01.addAll(myArrayList02);
    for(StringBuilder ele:myArrayList01)
        System.out.print(ele+ " ");

    myArrayList02.set(1, new StringBuilder("TWO"));
    System.out.println("=====================");
    for(StringBuilder ele:myArrayList01)
        System.out.print(ele+" ");

    System.out.println(myArrayList02.get(0)==myArrayList01.get(3));
```

*The output is:
 
uno dos tres one two three

 ===================
 
uno dos tres one two three

true*

Comment: "*This implies any change in the elements of myArrayList02 will be reflected in myArrayList01 too.*" - This assumption is wrong. `myArrayList02` references some `StringBuilder` with content `"two"` at index `1`. Through calling `myArrayList01.addAll(myArrayList02)`, `myArrayList01` now references the aforementioned `StringBuilder`. If you update the second index of `myArrayList02`, this is not reflected in `myArrayList01`.

Comment: "addAll() only creates a shallow copy of the arraylist" where did you get that from? At least the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) is very *simple*: "**Appends** all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's Iterator"

Answer (score 0):

The two `ArrayList`s hold references to the same objects. When you use `set`, you replace the reference in the list with a different one, so the other list is **not** updated, as you've seen. If you actually modify one of the objects in the list, it would be reflected in both lists, e.g.:

```
list1.get(4).append("some text);
```

Answer (score 0):

`addAll()` does not "create a shallow copy of the list".  It creates new references to the same objects referred to by the list being copied, and adds them to the target list.  These references in the target list are distinct from the references in the original source list.

When you modify the source list you change one of its references, but this does not affect the copy of the reference that was placed into the target list.

The following depicts the state after `target.addAll(source)`, where the references contained in the source list have been coped to the target list.

```
       target                              source
      +------+          +-------+         +------+
      | ref  +----------> Item1 |  +------+ ref  |
      +------+          +-------+  |      +------+
      | ref  +-------+             |  +---+ ref  |
      +------+       |  +-------+  |  |   +------+
      | ref  +-----+ +--> Item2 |  |  |
      +------+     |    +-------+  |  |
      | ref  +--+  |               |  |
      +------+  |  |    +-------+  |  |
                |  +----> Item3 <--+  |
                |       +-------+     |
                |                     |
                |       +-------+     |
                +-------> Item4 <-----+
                        +-------+
```

I you now modify one of the references in `source` to point somewhere else, say, by

```
source.set(1,someOtherItem)
```

it has no effect on the contents of `target`.